# Creating a Random Number Generator srand and rand undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random, undefined

I'm using virtual studio and it keeps tagging srand and rand as being undefined.  Project is setup as a visual c++ win32 project.  #include cstdlib and #include ctime are implemented as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;



void randomNumberGen();

int main() {
randomNumberGen();
return 0;
}

 void randomNumberGen()
 {
 ofstream randomNumberDocument;
 unsigned seed = time(0);
 srand(seed);

 for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
 cout << rand() << endl;
 }
```

I know this is not a fully functioning program yet and fstream is not implemeted yet.  I wanted to fix problems before moving on

Comment: "win32 project" - apart from anything else, it should be a "console application".

Comment: `void main` is wrong. You should get better learning material.

Comment: warning nitpicking: you are using the word "implementing" in a strange way. E.g. of course `fstream` is already implemented, you dont have to do this, you just have to inlcude the header and use it

Comment: `return;` at the end of a `void` function is redundant and should be omitted.

Comment: Take heart: " I wanted to fix problems before moving on" this is EXACTLY the right way to approach writing a program.

Comment: And back to the nitpicking: `time(0)` should be `time(NULL)` or `time(nullptr)`. `time` expects to be passed a pointer. 0 is not a pointer.

Comment: Can you compile and run the hello world program with your compiler setup?

Comment: Another suggestion: It doesn't matter here because `randomNumberGen` is only called once, but every time you call `seed` you restart the random number sequence (possibly with a new seed). You almost never want to restart the generator, so it is best to call to call it once near the top of `main` rather than inside a function where it can be called multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably problem with compiler. It should detect it. You can try to reinstall or update compiler. Or you can use `c` library `<stdlib.h>`. I would give com but i don't have reputation for that. :D

Comment: Yes, it was a problem with the compiler.  SDK 8.1 was optional and I didn't install it.  Uninstalling and reinstalling with all options activated fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: Well, i'm Linux user so when my compiler don't work i refresh(reinstall) it. :D. Habit sorry.